# Install virtual audio on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound

I want to install virtual audio.

Is there any good virtual audio software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install anything to create a purely virtual audio device in ALSA. Load snd-aloop with the following command:

```
modprobe snd-aloop
```

You also asked about a good virtual audio software. Another software that may be useful is alsa-utils which is run from the terminal:

```
sudo apt install alsa-utils
```